# Processing large dataset in batch, but the processing time of each batch keeps increasing

Tags: python, bigdata, python-multiprocessing

I have a big file with 150Gb text data. I write a simple Python code in Python3.5 environment to process data in batch with a `for` loop. However, I found out the processing time of each batch increases gradually.

I try to disable the garbage collection (`gc.disable()`). But it does not work.

For each batch, I call the RESTful API to process the data with multi-threads.

For each batch, there are 5000 lines of data record. I submitted them with 15 threads. After 5000 lines are done, I submit another 5000 lines. The processing time of these 5000 lines of data increase gradually

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 

def multithread_call(input):
    pool = ThreadPool(15) 
    output = pool.map(REST_API, input)
    return output

def REST_API(data):
    headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json','Connection':'close'}
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
    result = json.loads(r.text)
    return result

 batch = get_batch_data(5000)  # 5000 lines of data
 while len(batch)!=0:
      batch_result = multithread_call(batch) # data processing
      save(batch_result)
      batch = get_batch_data(5000)  # 5000 lines of data
```

Comment: This isn't enough information.  What are you doing when you process the data?

Comment: For each batch, I call the RESTful API to process the data. r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

Comment: So you are posting batches of the 150Gb data, to have it processed elsewhere, and that "elsewhere processing" takes longer each time, while the batches are always the same size?

Comment: This is still not enough information.  If you replace the REST API calls with something else, does it still gradually take longer?

Comment: @Evert Yes. the batches are always the same size, but the processing time takes longer.

Comment: @Colin I have replaced the REST API calls with other function which process data locally. It does not gradually take longer.

Comment: Then it sounds like a problem with your REST API calls...

Comment: Show us the (simplified) code where you read the data and loop over it, performing the POST call. We can't judge if the issue is on your side or not without seeing your code.

Comment: @Evert@Colin I have update the code.

Comment: Since you're doing the POST call on different subprocesses, it's hard to actually say that the processing time increasing for each batch, since the batches are not submitted sequentially, after the previous one has finished.

Comment: Try using a smaller `ThreadPool` and see what affect it has on processing time.

Comment: Most likely, the server that's doing the processing gets overloaded: you're submitting 15 jobs at once, the server may only handle 4 at a time. If each job takes a 1 minute, you'll get 4 back in 1 minute, then the next 4 have taken 2 minutes total (1 minute waiting), next 4 3 minutes etc. Try running with 1 process at a time, not 15, and see what you get.

Comment: @Evert the batches are submitted sequentially, after the previous one finished.

Comment: Are you sure? You seem to be running 15 threads at once.

Comment: @Evert Let me clarify. For each single batch, there are 5000 lines of data record. I submitted them with 15 threads. After 5000 lines are done, I submit another 5000 lines. The processing time of these 5000 lines of data increase gradually.

Comment: So you are saying there's an outer loop around the code in your question? Because we don't see that loop, making it hard to assess what's going. I thought that `input` simply contains all your data, and it's split up into 15 batches.

Comment: You mention 5000 lines of data for each batch. I assume that means that `pool.map` splits the data into 5000 pieces. If so, that means there are 5000 API calls per batch. I don't know whether that's an internal or external URL, how long a single line takes to process, but that sounds like quite a lot of POST requests. Perhaps the server on the other side is simply tuned to rate limit the number of incoming requests from a single IP address. It might be useful to get some numbers on processing time for a single request, API calls / minute and any limits imposed by the actual service.